# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: org/apache/xml/serializer/ExtendedContentHandler

Tags: java, xml, apache, xalan, serialization

I am using Jasper Report to run the reports using **jdk1.4** and **tomcat 4.1**. I am getting following error. I have **xalan-2.7.1.jar**, **xercesImpl.jar** and **serializer-2.7.1.jar**

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
>   org/apache/xml/serializer/ExtendedContentHandler  at
>   org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1321)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2400)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.applyTemplateToNode(TransformerImpl.java:2270)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transformNode(TransformerImpl.java:1356)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.run(TransformerImpl.java:3447)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerHandlerImpl.endDocument(TransformerHandlerImpl.java:408)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipSpaces(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DTDConfiguration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TrAXFilter.parse(TrAXFilter.java:164)
>     at org.apache.fop.apps.Driver.render(Driver.java:481)

I am using following code for rendering report

> ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); Driver driver
>   = new Driver(); driver.setRenderer(Driver.RENDER_PDF); driver.setOutputStream(out); driver.render(input.getParser(),
>   input.getInputSource());

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the serializer-2.7.1.jar and replace it with serializer-2.7.0.jar, then restart. It seems to be a known and documented issue with the classes in serializer jar conflicting with the classes in the newer versions of xalan, xerces.

Reference:

http://support.esri.com/de/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/33857

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @BatScream. The error is still occurs when I remove the serializer-2.7.1.jar.

Comment: Are you getting classnotfound Error? If so what is that class. Can you check if those classes are available in other versions of xalan or xerces.

Comment: remove serializer-2.7.1 and use serializer-2.7.0. ExtendedContentHandler is present in both serializer-2.7.1 as well as xalan-2.7.1.jar. This could have been the problem.

Comment: Using serializer-2.7.0 instead of serializer-2.7.1 the issue is fixed. Thank you @BatScream.